# Print array in existing li and span

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, magento

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="prices-tier items">
   <li class="item">
      <span class="price-container price-tier_price tax weee">
      <span data-price-amount="207.53" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">207,53&nbsp;€</span></span>
      </span>
      </span> <strong class="benefit"<span class="percent tier-0">&nbsp;10</span>%</strong>                            
   </li>
   <li class="item">
      <span class="price-container price-tier_price tax weee">
      <span id="1" data-price-amount="196" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">196,00&nbsp;€</span></span>
      </span>
      <span id="TaxInfo">
      </span>  <strong class="benefit">risparmia<span class="percent tier-1">&nbsp;15</span>%</strong>                            
   </li>
</ul>
```

so my JS code is:

```
var tierArray = jQuery('.items  li').find('span.price-tier_price > span[data-price-type=""]').map(function() {return jQuery(this).attr('data-price-amount');}).get();
var final = function(x) {
return x * 1.10;
}
var tierformatedPrice = [];
tierArray.forEach(function(item) {
item = final(item);
tieritem = priceUtils.formatPrice(parseInt(item));
tierformatedPrice.push(tieritem);
});
```

I want to read,modify and print prices
They are stored in tierformatedPrice array but now I'm stuck to print back prices in HTML...Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't working.

Comment: I can't print back prices in my html,I have the values on tierformatedPrice array but I can't print each value on each li

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4ayzch9u/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Yes,I need to print back ONLY values and NOT "10%","risparmia 15%" in HTML without modifing CSS.
https://imgur.com/a/YRTYwuO

Comment: How about just adding a `$('.benefit').remove();` ? Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4ayzch9u/